# Running multiple threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm having a very weird problem.I'm working on an assignment that involves building a simulation of figures moving on a 2d "chessboard". Each figure is represented by an object implementing the Runnable interface.
The problem is that when I attempt to run each object in a different thread like so:

```
    ArrayList< Thread > playerThreads = new ArrayList< Thread >();
    ArrayList< Player > players = p.getSpawnedPlayers(); // This method returns all Runnable objects
    for ( Player pl : players )
        playerThreads.add( new Thread( pl ) );

    for ( Thread pt : playerThreads )
    {
        pt.run();
    }
```

For some reason, only the first thread starts.And I'm pretty certain of this, the run() method of the
player class looks like this:

```
public void run()
{
    System.out.println( "Player " + this.hashCode() + " starts moving..." );
    ...
}
```

I only get output from a single object.I doublechecked and made sure that both ArrayLists contain the right number of objects.
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To start a thread you have to call `pt.start()`, not `pt.run()`. See the JavaDoc for all the details.

Comment: *facepalm* I totally forgot that it was the correct way to do it.Silly me:)

Comment: I couldn't at the time of my comment, too soon after I posted the question I assume:)

Comment: Care to edit this answer a bit to flesh it out for posterity?  What happens when the user calls `run()` instead of start?  Thanks.