# child thread blocks parent thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        }
    }).run();
    System.out.println("Bye");
}
```

In the main thead, I create a new thread, which will print "hello" every second. Why the final "Bye" never got print? In the other word, why the child thread blocks the main thread?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem running multiple threads in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235487/problem-running-multiple-threads-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you are calling `run()`, instead of `start()`.

You must never call `run()` directly. If you call `start()`, the program will call `run()` for you, in a different thread. (Like you wanted.) By calling `run()` yourself, you are going into the `run()` method with the parent thread, and get stuck in an eternal loop, with your parent thread.